# Copying the base build from these websites

Tags: javascript, html, web

Is it posible to copy the htlm of one of these websites(or some of the features) and change them a litle?

what do I have to do?

http://line25.com/articles/25-innovative-websites-that-buck-the-design-trends#:7v

Comment: When you visit the website, open your browser's developer tools.  All of the client-side code is available right there.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have a save function that will download the current page's HTML, as well as scripts and other assets that the page links to. However, don't expect to then open it up and have it work. Relative path names in the source might no longer resolve, there may be server side features that you of course won't have access to, and depending on your browser not all assets might download.

**However,** if you're doing this to learn, that's one thing. If you're simply trying to rip off someone's design, I would not recommend that and depending on the assets (image rights, for example) could land you in trouble.